# How to call keyboard accessibility events to get selected value using angular 9?

Tags: javascript, angular, keyboard, accessibility, angular9

I have the following code. It is working fine with `(click)` event. But, it is not working with the keyboard keys events(like: `tab` to focus, `enter` key, `up arrow` key and `down arrow` key). I am not sure what's went wrong and how to achieve the same `(click)` functionality to work with keyboard keys events. I am new to this accessibility, Can anyone please help me in this to achieve the required solution. Thanks in advance.

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  isData=true;
  data = [
          {"title":"TestOne","description":"SampleDesc1"},
          {"title":"TestTwo","description":"SampleDesc2"},
          {"title":"TestThree","description":"SampleDesc3"},
          {"title":"TestFour","description":"SampleDesc4"}
        ];

  getValue(val){
    console.log("Selected value: "+val);
  }

}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<div *ngIf="isData; else noData">
  <div *ngFor = "let item of data">
    <div tabindex="0"
      (keyup.arrowup)="getValue(item.title)"
      (keyup.enter)="getValue(item.title)"
      (keyup.arrowdown)="getValue(item.title)"
      (click)="getValue(item.title)">{{item.title}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
<ng-template  #noData>
    data is not available
</ng-template>
```

[Created Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter-ocsa1y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: What do you want to do with arrow keys? Navigation?
You just show the value in the console and It happens currently

Comment: @HojjatollahBakhtiyariKiya Thanks for your response. Yes, I want to show the value in the console with keyboard arrow keys as well according to my requirements to provide keyboard support for my application(accessibility support).

Comment: The program already prints the result in console when you trigger keyup, ...

Comment: I think you are unclear.

Comment: I have got some solution at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56608536/angular-i-want-to-move-focus-of-div-from-to-another-on-arrow-key-buttons#:~:text=For%20right%20arrow%20key%2C%20you,focus%20to%20the%20previous%20element.&text=Working%20Code%20%2D%20https%3A%2F%2Fstackblitz,%2Fedit%2Fangular%2D5qxicw.