# Angular find element attribute doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angularjs

I am following this simple article: [Arrow Keys to Navigate](https://blog.lkatney.com/2017/09/11/arrow-keys-to-navigate-on-form-angularjs/). There is a problem with this line towards the bottom:

```
var nextInput = angular.element(angular.element.find('[arrow-keys-index="'+nextIndex+'"]'));
```

Basically, what it needs to do is find an element from my HTML where the attribute and value match the string so it can then call to focus that element. HTML example of what it needs to find would look like this:

```
<input type="text" arrow-keys-index="0:2" />
```

I am getting an error on that line:

> TypeError: angular.element.find is not a function
> at HTMLInputElement. (arrow-keys-index.js:47:65)
> at defaultHandlerWrapper (angular.js:3795:11)
> at HTMLInputElement.eventHandler (angular.js:3783:9)
> at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:406:1)
> at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28564:1)
> at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:405:1)
> at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:178:1)
> at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:487:1)
> at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1600:1)
> at HTMLInputElement.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone-evergreen.js:1626:1)

Any thoughts?

Comment: The error looks like Angular, while your links seems to be angularJs..?

Comment: @MikeOne Yes, I must admit that I am confused about that. The project I am maintaining is older. It is now a hybrid. Definitely now Angular but I thought used to be AngularJS. I think this page I am working on is of the older variety. Just in case it is Angular, is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: In Angular (not in AngularJs) the "arrow-keys-index" becomes in a Directive. See an e.g. in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56608536/angular-i-want-to-move-focus-of-div-from-to-another-on-arrow-key-buttons/56620003#56620003). NOTE: We need take account when read an Article if is about Angular or AngularJs. futhermore if is a very old article we should check also the version of Angular

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your nextIndex == "0:2"

inject the `$element` into the controller, then:

```
var nextInput = $element.find('[arrow-keys-index="'+nextIndex+'"]');
```