# How do i set arrow key focus on these button in angular while pressing the left and right arrow keys?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, rxjs

Here when i press the arrow keys left and right its not focusing or i cannot navigate or choose these button using my arrow keys, but when consoling the values of these keycode its getting printed according to the key pressed,I need to know how to gain focus on the html when pressing the arrow keys so that the buttons can be navigated through using arrow keys,It would be a great help if someone can provide me with a solution.

component.html

```
 <ng-template #content let-modal>
 <div class="modal-header">
 <h3 class="modal-title">Accept Offer</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
 <p>Do you really want to accept the offer?</p>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary tab" (click)="onAcceptOffer()" arrow-div>Submit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary tab" (click)="modal.dismiss('Crossclick');
   isClicked=false" arrow-div>Cancel</button></div>
 </ng-template>
```

Services.ts

```
export class KeyBoardService {
  keyBoard:Subject<any>=new Subject<any>();
  sendMessage(message:any)
  {
    this.keyBoard.next(message)
  }
}
```

directive.ts

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[arrow-div]',
})
export class ArrowDivDirective {
  constructor(private keyboardService: KeyBoardService, public element: ElementRef, private render: Renderer2) {
    this.render.setAttribute(this.element.nativeElement, "tabindex", "0")
  }


  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyUp(e) {

    switch (e.keyCode) {
      case 38:
        this.keyboardService.sendMessage({ element: this.element, action: 'UP' })
        break;
      case 37:
        this.keyboardService.sendMessage({ element: this.element, action: 'LEFT' })
        break;
      case 40:
        this.keyboardService.sendMessage({ element: this.element, action: 'DOWN' })
        break;
      case 39:
        this.keyboardService.sendMessage({ element: this.element, action: 'RIGTH' })
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

component.ts

```
columns:number=2;
  @ViewChildren(ArrowDivDirective) inputs:QueryList<ArrowDivDirective>

  constructor(private keyboardService:KeyBoardService){}
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.keyboardService.keyBoard.subscribe(res=>{
      this.move(res)
    })
  }
  move(object)
  {
    const inputToArray=this.inputs.toArray()
    let index=inputToArray.findIndex(x=>x.element==object.element);
    switch (object.action)
    {
      case "UP":
        index-=this.columns;
        break;
      case "DOWN":
        index+=this.columns;
        break;
      case "LEFT":
        index--;
        break;
      case "RIGTH":
        index++;
        break;
      case "RIGTH":
        index++;
        break;
    }

    if (index>=0 && index<this.inputs.length)
    {
      inputToArray[index].element.nativeElement.focus();
    }
  }
```

Comment: when i press the arrow keys i need to navigate through these button submit and cancel so its not focussing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine the code goes from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56608536/angular-i-want-to-move-focus-of-div-from-to-another-on-arrow-key-buttons/56620003#56620003)

The "problem" with this approach is that you should focus one HTMLelement before you can use the arrows keys.

We can take another approach: the service subscribe to document.fromEvent('document')

Imagine a service like

```
import {map,filter,tap} from 'rxjs/operators'
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class KeyBoardService {
  keyBoard:Subject<any>=new Subject<any>();
  subscription:Subscription
  
  sendMessage(message:any)
  {
    this.keyBoard.next(message)
  }
  init()
  {
    if (!this.subscription)
      this.subscription=fromEvent(document,'keydown').pipe(
        filter((e:Event)=>{
          const el=document.activeElement
          const ev=(e as KeyboardEvent)

          //only want if the key is an arrow
          const isArrow=ev.keyCode>=37 && ev.keyCode<=40

          //and is the "body" or is arrow down and we are not
          //in a select or is an "arrow-div"
          return isArrow && (el.tagName== 'body' || 
                            (ev.keyCode==40 && el.tagName!='SELECT') || 
                            el.getAttribute('arrow-div')==='')
        }),
        map(e=>{
        const obj={element:document.activeElement,action:null}
        switch ((e as KeyboardEvent).keyCode) {
          case 38:
            obj.action='UP' 
            break;
          case 37:
            obj.action='LEFT' 
            break;
          case 40:
            obj.action='DOWN'
            break;
          case 39:
            obj.action='RIGTH' 
            break;
        }
        return obj
      })).subscribe(res=>{
        this.sendMessage(res)
      })
  }
  destroy()
  {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe()
    this.subscription=null;
  }
}
```

And a directive like

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[arrow-div]',
})
export class ArrowDivDirective {
  element:HTMLElement
  constructor(private keyboardService: KeyBoardService, 
        private el: ElementRef, private render: Renderer2) {
    this.render.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, "tabindex", "0")
    this.element=this.el.nativeElement;
  }
}
```

See that, in this case we not use @HotListener, and that the "element" property is the HTMLElement (not the nativeElement)

We can use in our component like

```
@ViewChildren(ArrowDivDirective) inputs: QueryList<ArrowDivDirective>;

  constructor(private keyboardService: KeyBoardService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.keyboardService.init();
    this.keyboardService.keyBoard.subscribe((res) => {
      this.move(res);
    });
  }
  move(object: any) {
    const inputToArray = this.inputs.toArray();
    let index = inputToArray.findIndex((x) => x.element == object.element);
    if (index < 0) index = 0;
    else {
      switch (object.action) {
        case 'UP':
          index -= this.columns;
          break;
        case 'DOWN':
          index += this.columns;
          break;
        case 'LEFT':
          index--;
          break;
        case 'RIGTH':
          index++;
          break;
        case 'RIGTH':
          index++;
          break;
      }
    }

    if (index >= 0 && index < this.inputs.length) {
      inputToArray[index].element.focus();
    }
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.keyboardService.destroy();
  }
```

See that it's necesary "initialize" our service (to began the subscription to fromEvent(document,'keydown'),and, in ngOnDestroy, remove the subscription

The new [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dgyjb3?file=src%2Fapp%2Farrow-div.directive.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fkeyboard.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: In the service why is the tag name body and select?

Comment: I want that if, you has the focus on the body, any arrow select the fist "arrow-div". As I listen the event in document, if we has the focus in an input only want that goes to the fisrt "arrow-div" if you press the arrow down -else if you're editing and use the arrows left and right, again the focus goes to the first "arrow-div". Well, when we have an "select" the arrow down is to select the next option. So in this case I don't want to do nothing even the arrow down is execute. I can control this cases in the app.component but I think it's better idea filter this cases in services

Comment: Actually this code is working for buttons which are not inside modals,when a button is placed inside an ng-template modal pop-up the focus is not gathering

Comment: I had updated the code snippet

Comment: I defined an object with the properties: element and action so, I need only change the property "action" in the switch instead of create a new object -else typescript in strict mode don't allow me create "on fly" a new property to the object-. Note also that thanks to the filter always fall in any of the cases defined.